# xbap with winform popups and MAC

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, macos, xbap

Testing WPF XBAP solutions, I'm able to use winform forms as modal dialogs (popup window).
And I'm amazed that running it from my internet host server, once I have added the website as "Trusted Site" in IE, and having declared the WPF as "Full Trust" I can have the full winform capabilities, including LINQ querying a SQL Server DB on another server! (Without using WCF).

PLUS! I was able to run this app. from Safari (windows version) and Google chrome!
PLUS: I can run it in Firefox, but Firefox is hanging after a few clicks...??? (Well to be honest, Firefox is frequently hanging on my VISTA computer, whatever the website ...)

My question is: **will the app. run on a MAC**, wether using IE or Safari?
Does Winform popups need the .NET framework to be installed on the client computer?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run an XBAP on anything but a Windows platform that has .Net framework installed.  Only choice would be a Virtual machine on OS X, and even then, it now seems like IE is the only choice within there.  Latest firefox, chrome or safari, even with the copy dll hacks is an exercise in futility.